# realloc() causes segmentation fault

Tags: c++

I have this code:

```
Perro **obj = NULL;

obj = (Perro**)malloc(10*sizeof(Perro*));


for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    obj[i] = new Perrito((char*)"d",i);
}

realloc(obj,12*sizeof(Perro*));


for (int i = 9; i < 12; i++)
{
    obj[i] = new Perrito((char*)"d",i);
}

for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    Perrito *p;
    p = (Perrito*)obj[i];
    cout << p->getEdad() << endl;
}
```

When I read my object I see memory dumped (segmentation fault) error.
When I comment out the `realloc` line and reduce the last for length item it works normally, but I need to use `realloc` to increase my polifirmist object length.

Comment: Don't even think of using `realloc()` on things allocated with `new` — use either `new` and `delete` or … well, actually, if you're learning C++, now is a good time to forget all about `malloc()`, `realloc()`, `free()` etc.  Use `new` and `delete`.  Only!  That is, if you can't use `vector<Perrito>` or something similar.  The `(char *)"d"` casts are worrying, too.  The constructor should probably take a `const char *` (which would render the cast irrelevant), or you should use `const_cast<char *>("d")` to indicate the type of cast you're doing — but you shouldn't need to do that.

Comment: He's using `realloc` on something allocated with `malloc`. He's only passing `obj` to `realloc`, and `obj` just contains ordinary pointers. (I agree about the cast.)

Comment: use vectors, don't use new and delete. Stop using c-style casts.

Comment: I NEED a coleccion of polyformics shapes sorry for me languis i'm from vzla  yes i only can use new malloc realloc delete and free but how can i get a coleccion of poliformics shapes only whit new a cant use vector !

Answer (score 2):

```
obj = realloc(obj,12*sizeof(Perro*));
```

pointer will change after realloc!

Comment: True, but only part of the problem.  An important part of the problem.  The code leaks `obj[9]` from the first allocation loop.  I'm suspicious that there'll be other leaks too, but the clean-up code isn't shown.  Using a `vector` would solve many problems.

Comment: If `realloc` fails this line of code causes a memory leak.

Comment: WHY ! A SAW THAT THE POSICITION 0 I MEAN OBJ[0] ALWAYS WILL RETURN 0 OR NULL POINTER AND I WILL LOST ALMOST THE 10 FIST POSICITONS! WHY AND WHAT I SHOULD TODO THASKS!

Answer (score 0):

SHOOULD BE BETTER IF I....

```
Perro *obj[40];

perro[0] = new Perrito;
Perro[1] = new PerritoOther;
...
Perro[39]...

THEN IF THE USER WHAT TO ADD OTHER THINGS
MY TEACHER SAID YOU MUST USE REALLOC ?!  WHY,WHAT CAN I DO ?
```